# Control font size in HTML and hide the change

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following java script for changing the font size and font family according to the URL parameters. 
Example URL: www.myUrl.com/?font-size=30,font-family=sans

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function shoham(){
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

    for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
         // Do something with the element here
        var myTag = all[i];
        var fs =window.location.href.split("?")[1].replace("font-size=","")+"px";
        if (fs == "")
            myTag.style.fontSize = "18px";
        else
            myTag.style.fontSize = fs;
        var lh = window.location.href.split("?")[2].replace("line-height=","")+"px";
        if (lh == "")
            myTag.style.lineHeight = "26px";
        else
            myTag.style.lineHeight = lh;
        var ff = window.location.href.split("?")[3].replace("font-family=","");
        if (ff == 1)
             myTag.style.fontFamily="handlee";
        if (ff == 2)
             myTag.style.fontFamily="miriam";
        if (ff == 3)
             myTag.style.fontFamily="sans";
        if (ff == 4)
             myTag.style.fontFamily="flamenco";
        if (ff == "")
             myTag.style.fontFamily="sans";                  
    }
}
</script>
  </head>

  <body onload="shoham();">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <span class="span12">
          <div class="div-1">
```

This is not a good solution since I can see the fonts changing.
I would like to ask if any of you knows a "best practice" way to do this without see the fonts changing.

I would like to set the document to be invisible and make it visible only after the font were loaded. (since currently I see the change happening)

Thanks

Comment: Ehm... you want to change the font, but so that it doesn't show? Then why change it at all?

Comment: Oh, wait, you mean to want to avoid FOUF, right?

Comment: Then just make the text invisible at first, and only show it when the style has been applied.

Comment: @MrLister Thats exactly what I want, ow can I do that?

Comment: OK, because I thought we were headed here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKorP55Aqvg (red/transparent ink).

Comment: @MrLister I also updated the question to be more clear

Comment: @NinjaCat I watched the first two minutes... are you trying to imply that this is not possible :) ?